# Is EF Core Migrations automatically ran when I run my project?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I created a simple Web API project to test out EF Migrations. I've called Add-Migration Initial in Package Manager Console and the Initial migration along with the folder was created. Now I ran my project and I was expecting it to create the database automatically. But it doesn't and it throws login error.

I've called Update-Database and the database was created.

Shouldn't it automatically create the database on access of context? What about when I add a new migration file? Will it automatically update my database on run when it sees the snapshot is different from the database (or does it use the migrations table)?

To summarize, the questions are:

1. Can EF Core Migrations automatically create the database on run of application?
2. Can EF Core Migrations automatically update the database on run of application when it detects there is difference?
3. What does it use to compare the difference? The actual DB structure and the Snapshot?
4. If it automatically updates, What happens if I manually delete a migration? The snapshot and Migration table in DB would be out of sync, right? What will happen?
5. If its not possible to automatic create/update on run, how do you deploy the db and changes to your customers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EF core doesn't** support `Automatic Migrations`.So you have to do it manually.

> From the perspective of automatic migrations as a feature, we are not
>   planning to implement it in EF Core as experience has showed code-base
>   migrations to be a more manageable approach.

You can read full story here : [**Not to implement Automatic Migrations**](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6214)

You can see how to do it using [**.NET Core CLI**](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet.html)

See how to do it using [**Package Manager Console (Visual Studio)**](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/miscellaneous/cli/powershell.html)

Comment: Ok, then one question. How do you normally deploy the database changes/updates to customer if you need to?

Comment: I just change my `connection string` as `production one` on the `web.config` and run below command on `package manger console`. `PM> Update-Database`

Comment: Sorry, last question. Do you mean you install VS in customer computer so you can use Package Manager Console? Or can you run that without VS?

Comment: if you can, go ahead and do that way.But if you cannot install `VS` on the client machine then you can use `CLI commands` to do the `data migration` without `VS`.please see the `2nd link` on my post above.you can ask any number of quetions. no problem at all :D

Comment: @Sampath dbContext.Database.Migrate(); automatically runs migrations created using dotnet ef migrations add ..., even for a compiled binary and you migrations are added to the assembly, hence need not to be shipped separately

Answer (score 4):

You can run your migrations automatically in `Startup.cs` by adding:

```
var dbFactory = new DataContextFactory();
var dbContext = dbFactory.Create(new DbContextFactoryOptions());
dbContext.Database.Migrate();
```

`DataContextFactory` is the factory that implements `IDbContextFactory<DataContext>`.